# django how to add extra arguments in the generic class

Tags: django

Some time ago I made a simple blog app with comment feature in each article. Everything works fine. Here is my models, urls, view, and template :

```
# model:
class Article(models.Model):
......
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

# app/urls:
url(r'^article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(),name='article_detail'), 
url(r'^article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/comment/$',views.BlogCommentCreate.as_view(), name='blog_comment'),         

# views:        
class BlogCommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):    
......
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  
    context = super(BlogCommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['article'] = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])      
    return super(BlogCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)        

# template        
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog_comment' article.slug %}">Add a new comment</a></p>
```

But when I modified them to this, since I want a full URL of my article:

```
# models:
def get_absolute_url(self):

return reverse('blog:article_detail',
    kwargs={
       'year': self.date_created.strftime('%Y'),
       'month': self.date_created.strftime('%m'),
       'day': self.date_created.strftime('%d'),
       'slug': self.slug})

# urls:           
url(r'^article/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
url(r'^article/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/comment/$',views.BlogCommentCreate.as_view(), name='blog_comment'),
```

Error appeared:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/article/generating-dummy-post/comment/
Reverse for 'article_detail' with arguments '('generating-dummy-post',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/article/(?P\\d{4})/(?P\\d{2})/(?P\\d{2})/(?P[-\\w]+)/$']
```

How can I add these (year, month, day) extra arguments in the article context into my view and template?

Comment: How and where do you use `get_absolute_url` in template?

Comment: What does your call to the url template tag look like now?  That might be the problem.

Comment: error appeared when I call to this {% url 'blog:blog_comment' article.slug %}